# How can I adjust the "Remind me later" time for upgrade Ubuntu notifications?

Tags: upgrade, notification, schedule

It seems like I am getting a pop up every day or every other day to upgrade Ubuntu.  I click on the "Remind me later" but "later" ends up being tomorrow!  I don't want to forget it entirely and do want to be reminded but just not every day. How can I set this to a week or a month or something?

Comment: What does your Software & Updates control panel say?

Comment: There is an option for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" but nothing about how this is scheduled.  Automatically check for updates is set to daily but this is not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about how to change the definition of "later" when checking the "Remind me later" box on the new Ubuntu version notification dialog.  I have no expectation of whether or not these two rather unrelated items are linked by the same schedule.  I want to be reminded of a new Ubuntu version on a different schedule from the daily update schedule.

Comment: Are "security updates" the same as "New Ubuntu Version" notifications?  I have Security Updates set to "Download and Install Automatically" so I am NOT refusing any of these.  I don't refuse normal updates.  The New Ubuntu Version is not a normal update; it is a real BFD.  I want to be totally prepared, with my slate clean before I go down that road.  So, I want to be reminded occasionally that there is a new version available, not just every day.  However, normal updates to the version I'm running now will get applied and I don't mind being reminded daily for those.

Comment: Oh, your Question was unclear on the phrasing. Lots of people say "update Ubuntu" when they mean the daily/weekly updates. Seems like you're talking about a *new release of Ubuntu*. That's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the "*A new release of Ubuntu is available*" pop-up: No, there's no way to change the frequency of the pop-up unless you want to dig deep and modify the Python code. Your choice is on or off.

- Kudos for wanting to be methodical and prepared for your release-upgrade. That attitude will prevent a lot of problems!
- You can turn it off in the Software and Updates control Panel. Turning it off is unwise for most users -- they might miss the release-upgrade window entirely, and things get ugly after that.
- It's Open Source software. If you decide to dig into the Python code and add a feature, be sure to contribute that feature back upstream so the whole community benefits.